# Java store onaction in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, button, javafx

So I'm making a login system. Based on the role your account has when you log in, it displays role specific buttons. For instance if you login as an employee, you get to see two buttons called RequestStatus and RegisterMissing. If you login as a manager, you get to see the buttons RequestStatus, RegisterMissing, Reports and UserRoles. 
After a bit of trail and error (As I am a beginner in java) I managed to make it work!

CODE:

```
@FXML
private TextField textUsername;

@FXML
private PasswordField textPassword;

Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
Scene scene;

ResultSet resultSet = null;

//Login for employee
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    Database db = new Database();
    String username = textUsername.getText();
    String password = textPassword.getText();
    int usrID = 0;
    int roleID = 0;
    //String RoleID = EmpSelect.getValue();
    String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM Employee "
            + "WHERE username = '%s' "
            + "and password = '%s' ",
            //+ "and RoleID = '%s' ", 
            username, password);

    infoBox("sql [" + sql + "]", "Success", null); 

    try {
        resultSet = db.executeResultSetQuery(sql);


        if (!resultSet.next()) {
            infoBox("Enter Correct Username and Password", "Failed", null);
        } else {
                //infoBox("Login Successfull", "Success", null);
            resultSet.first();
            usrID = resultSet.getInt("idEmployee");
            roleID = resultSet.getInt("RoleID");

            utilities.setEmployee(usrID, roleID);



            FXMLDocumentController controller = new FXMLDocumentController();
            utilities.newAnchorpane("EmployeeHomescreen", paneLogin);
            infoBox("Login Successfull", "Success", null);                  
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void infoBox(String infoMessage, String titleBar, String headerMessage) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle(titleBar);
    alert.setHeaderText(headerMessage);
    alert.setContentText(infoMessage);
    alert.showAndWait();
}
```

So basically what I'm doing here is that an employee of the company can login and it displays the result of the query just so that I know that it works.

```
import static com.mycompany.mavenproject2.LoginController.infoBox;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

/**
 *
 * @author John
 */
public class WorkerHomescreenController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private AnchorPane actualmain;

@FXML
private Pane mainpage;

@FXML
private Label label1;

@FXML
private Button but1, but2, but3, but4;

@FXML
private VBox VBPane;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    //infoBox("User ID = " + utilities.userID, "Success", null);
       Database db = new Database();
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String sqlMenu = String.format("SELECT * FROM Menu "
            + "WHERE idMenu IN (SELECT MenuID FROM MenuRoles WHERE RoleID = " + utilities.roleID + ") ");
            //+ "AND Active = True");
    try {
        resultSet = db.executeResultSetQuery(sqlMenu);
        int i=0;
        GridPane gpnael = new GridPane();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Button button = new Button(resultSet.getString("Link"));
            gpnael.add (button, i++, 1 );
            button.setStyle("-fx-font: 22 arial; -fx-base: #d81e05; "
                    + "-fx-background-radius: 0; -fx-border-width: 1 0 0 0; "
                    + "-fx-border-color: white; -fx-font-weight: bold; "
                    + "-fx-font-size: 18;");

            button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {
                        resultSet.getURL("Link");
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(WorkerHomescreenController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
Utilities utilities = new Utilities();

//Methods to open other pages
@FXML
private void openRequestStatus(ActionEvent event) {
    utilities.newPane("RequestStatus", but1, mainpage, label1);
}

@FXML
private void openRegisterMissing(ActionEvent event) {
    utilities.newPane("RegisterMissing", but2, mainpage, label1);
}

@FXML
private void openRequestTest(ActionEvent event) {
    utilities.newPane("RequestStatus", but3, mainpage, label1);
}

@FXML
private void openRegistertesting(ActionEvent event) {
    utilities.newPane("RegisterMissing", but4, mainpage, label1);
}
}
```

This is the controller of the page where you are redirected to after you login. This page is currently set up in a manner in which based on which RoleId the account you used to login with, it will generate the buttons with the info I have stored in my database.

Utilities controller:

```
   public static int userID;
   public static int roleID;

   @FXML
   public void setEmployee(int idEmployee, int RoleID) {
    this.userID = idEmployee;
    this.roleID = RoleID;
}
```

The Utilities controller is used to set the current employee.

My question is this:
My program currently works so that it generates buttons based on your account (Which is good!). What I want to do now is that the buttons have a link saved in the database as well. So that when the buttons are generated, it has a label and a link attached to it so that when you press the button it will go to the link that is attached to the button.

I hope this makes sense.

I know that in a .FXML file if you make a button inside of there you can give it an onAction event which makes it so that if you press the button it takes you to the correct page.

This is what my database looks like:

```
EMPLOYEE Table
idEmployee    firstname   lastname   username   password     RoleID
1             John        Doe        John123    Test123      1
2             Tim         Gardener   Tim123     Welcome123   2

ROLES Table
idRole     roleName
1          Employee
2          Manager

MENU Table
idMenu    Name    Link     
1         but1    RequestStatus
2         but2    RegisterMissing
3         but3    Reports
4         but4    UserRoles

MenuRoles Table
MenuID      RoleID
1           1
1           2
2           1
2           2
3           2
4           2
```

I hope you guys can help me with this problem and thank you for your time I appreciate it!

EDIT 1:
After reading the comment I edit a bit of my code.
The problem I'm having now is that the resultSet in resultSet.getURL("Link"); gives me an error saying: **"Local variabel is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final.**
After making the resultSet final it gives me another error saying 
final ResultSet resultSet = null;

This part now gives me an error saying:
resultSet = db.executeResultSetQuery(sqlMenu);
Cannot assign value to final variabel resultSet.

Comment: Instead of using FXML, you'll probably need to generate the button dynamically at runtime, which would then allow you to mange the action and properties better

Comment: Yes I would think so too. As you can in my code i posted above I do generate my button dynamically. But I can't figure out how to give the generated button a onAction link

Comment: Okay, create a custom `EventHandler` class which can take the required information you need in order to perform the required action of the button and apply it to the button via the `setOnAction` method

Comment: Okay, that sounds good. The problem is that I'm really a beginner in java and I really only know the basics. How would I create a custum EventHander class which takes the required information?

Comment: Aha nevermind. I fixed it like this: VBPane.getChildren().add(button);